# jar -tvf is working individually; but cannot work when included in bash script

Tags: bash, jar

I want to look contents of a jar file and search some class file in that jar in unix. 
What I did was `jar -tvf "path_to_file/file_name.jar" | grep class_name_to_search`. After this I can easily get desired result.

The problem comes when I use above command in a simple bash script. 
Below is my small script

`#!/bin/bash
nameToSearch=MyClassFileName
str=""
for i in $(find . -name "*.jar" | xargs -I@ -d"\n" echo \"@\" ); do # This is to append double quotes each line of the result of find command
    result=$(jar -tvf $i | grep $nameToSearch)
    echo "result: $result"
done`

Now what is get is below error

> result:
>
> java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:127)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:88)
>           at sun.tools.jar.Main.list(Main.java:977)
>           at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:222)

It gives desired result only when I do not append the result of find command with ""; but my requirement is to append the result with double quotes.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try "eval" like this: result=$(eval "jar -tvf $i | grep $nameToSearch")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is jar tvf only allows one file to be passed in.

The proper solution is the tell xargs to only use one parameter per command:
For Ex: jar tvf 1.jar; jar tvf 2.jar; ...

Try to modify your code in bash script to take care of following:

```
find . -name "*.jar" | xargs -n 1 jar tvf

or

find . -name "*.jar" | xargs -i jar tvf {}
```